# SQL server cursor run twice

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose i have a cursor which find data to update,

```
declare @index int;
declare cursor1 cursor for
select table1_index from table where (table1_date < dateadd(dd, -365, getdate()))

open cursor1 
fetch next from cursor1 into @index
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
  update table1
  set table1_field = SOMETHING
  where table1_index = @index

  if @ERROR = 0
  insert into audit_trail
  values(getdate(), table1_index)

  fetch next from cursor1 into @index
end
close cursor1 
deallocate cursor1
```

The above code is in a stored procedure and will be ran by a scheduler everyday (for example 12:00 am everyday).

My question is that if the scheduler ran the stored pro. in a time (for example, 17/06/2017 12:00 AM), and still running (for example in 17/06/2017 05:00 PM).

If i run the exact same code in (for example 17/06/2017 03:00 PM),
will the cursor select out data from the table which is updated? Or data from table that was not updated by the scheduler?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Depends on your transaction mode but assuming ACID compliance mode and a transaction boundary outside the procedure: It will use data from BEFORE the first procedure started running.

Comment: As you are having implicit transaction, the whole update statement might be blocking the further updates to the table and  17/06/2017 03:00 PM, will be waiting for the UPDATE statement to complete. As this is a huge UPDATE statement, it would have become Table lock or page lock and it would be blocking other transactions, till it is completed.

Comment: My update statement seems not huge and not won't take much time for executing. Anyway, thanks for your answer :).

Comment: May i have some information about the ACID compliance mode ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
declare cursor1 cursor for
select table1_index from table where (table1_date < dateadd(dd, -365, getdate())) 
and table1_index NOT IN (SELECT table1_index FROM audit_trail)
```

You need add condition `and table1_index NOT IN (SELECT table1_index FROM audit_trail)`. I hope it will work for you.